# Getting real world coordinates from Forge model

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Is it possible to get the real world coordinates form the original model in the Forge viewer? It looks like when a model is loaded into the Viewer it is placed with the center of the model in the origin of the Viewer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`viewer.model.getData().globalOffset` is what you are looking for: 
[Aligning Coordinate Systems in Autodesk Forge Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148538/aligning-coordinate-systems-in-autodesk-forge-viewer)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, the Forge viewer centres the model. In other words, the origin of the viewer coordinate system is the centroid of the model. The scale of the model remains unchanged. As a result, you can transform the original model coordinates to Forge viewer and vice versa simply by adding or subtracting the model centroid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Jeremey. Do you know if the original model coordinates is located somewhere in the viewer model? If a customer uploads a model we do not know these values.

Comment: Hi Frode, Probably not in general. Also, the details will always depend on the seed CAD file, e.g., the source authoring system.