# Map Autodesk forge viewer (ThreeJS) Coordinates to Original CAD Coordinates

Tags: three.js, coordinates, autocad, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I already know about the GlobalOffset thing, but still not able to map both.

All what I have is an X,Y,Z Values from the original CAD (before extraction and preparation) and I want to find them on the forge viewer to place objects, or any other operations.

Comment: Very curious why would someone down vote a question!!

Comment: Please accept our sincere apology for the delay, we had a backlog in the queue.

Could you share snapshots and detailed step-by-step instructions for reproducing the issue, please?

Comment: @EasonKang Thank you for your reply, I have point Location from the Original CAD, Say (72154.325,45687.12,15.324) But these coordinates don't map to anything in the rendered model in the Viewer (THREE Js Canvas), So, How can I map the original Coordinates to the rendered Coordinates

Comment: What is the difference between your question and the comments you posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148538/aligning-coordinate-systems-in-autodesk-forge-viewer/42163405?noredirect=1#comment79150091_42163405? I already answered your question there...

Answer (score 0):

According to Philippe, the viewer will move models or drawings around to the center of the viewport by minus the `viewer.model.globalOffset`.

Therefore, you have to minus the point location (x1, y1) with the (x2, y2) value of the `globalOffset`, then you will get what you want.