# Transform point from DWG model coordinates to autodesk forge viewer coordinates

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to display a point on model displayed in the Autodesk forge viewer. However I am unable to figure out how to transform the point.

The answer [Aligning Coordinate Systems in Autodesk Forge Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148538/aligning-coordinate-systems-in-autodesk-forge-viewer) doesn't work for me because `viewer.model.getData()` doesn't have a `globalOffset` property.

I have uploaded some example code along with the original dwg file here https://github.com/umarmohammed/forgeviewerdemo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I haven't received any responses from our engineering team. There seems not to have another way to obtain `viewportId` of current 2d view, and might have floating precision issue here, this is the issue I mentioned above. I will keep asking for them. So, here is the way I found to do point transformation from DWG coordinate system to the Viewers'.

1. Obtain current viewport id via `VertexBufferReader`, but you have to specify a 2d item(`dbId`) in the loaded view to read `viewportId` from it.

   ```
   var viewportId = null;
   function GeometryCallback(viewer) {
       this.viewer = viewer;
   }

   GeometryCallback.prototype.onLineSegment = function(x1, y1, x2, y2, vpId) {
       viewportId = vpId;
   }

   var fragId = 0;
   var m = viewer.impl.getRenderProxy(viewer.model, fragId);
   var vbr = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.VertexBufferReader(m.geometry, viewer.impl.use2dInstancing);
   vbr.enumGeomsForObject(dbId, new GeometryCallback());
   ```
2. Project DWG point back to Viewer coordinate system.

   ```
   var vpXform = viewer.model.getPageToModelTransform(viewportId).clone();
   var invVpXform = new WGS.LmvMatrix4(true);

   invVpXform.getInverse(vpXform, true);

   var ptInCadX = ...;
   var ptInCadY = ...;
   var verticesInViewer = new THREE.Vector3().set(ptInCadX, ptInCadY, 0).applyMatrix4(invVpXform);
   ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm unsure how to get the dbId and fragId. In my example would the correct dbId be `viewer.model.getData().instanceTree.nodeAccess.rootId`? How do I get the fragId from the dbId?

Comment: Select an item on the 2D view of the Viewer, and call `viewer.getSelection()` to get `dbId`. Afterward, `var it = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree; it.enumNodeFragments( dbId, function( fragId ) { console.log( fragId ) })`

Comment: There is another way to obatin the instancTree, `viewer.getObjectTree(function( it ) { console.log( it ) }, functio( code, msg ) { console.error( code, msg ) })`

Comment: getting the dbId and fragId inside the `Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT` handler works perfectly. However I need to perform the transformation when model is loaded. The way I did this was to call `viewer.select(dbId, Autodesk.Viewing.SelectionMode.REGULAR)` inside the `Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT`. I have updated the code on my github repository to demonstrate this. However this is a very convoluted way of doing this. Is there a simpler way to do the transformation when the model is loaded? Preferably one that doesn't involve selecting an item first.

Comment: If you want to transform the model while loaded, you can try to pass this option to `Viewer3D#loadModel`: `const  modelOpts = {
    placementTransform: new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation( x1, y1, z1 ),
    globalOffset: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }
};
`